# Using find / identify for image integrity check

Tags: mogrify

The following command line was taken from another post. How can it be adapted to execute with paths/file names using spaces?

find . | xargs -I % sh -c 'identify -regard-warnings -verbose % > /dev/null 2>&1;echo % $?'